# If any 3 cells contains ABC = True

Tags: excel, formula

So my questions is how would I do a formula to show true if "Win" is in any of the 3 cells. I don't need to know if it is there more than once just if there is one in any of the 3 games.

**Example**

```
Name  Game1 Game2 Game3
John  blank blank win     = True
Greg  win   win   blank   = True
Cris  blank blank blank   = False
Matt  blank WIN   blank   = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"win")>=1
```

[image]